# A simple explanation on G-expectation

Tags: mathematical-statistics, finance

I came across some articles on arxiv [Optimal Multiple Stopping Problems under g-expectation](https://arxiv.org/abs/1912.07843) and [Optimal Stopping under G-expectation](https://arxiv.org/abs/1812.08626) that are applications of Brownian motion to stock market trading. Are there any materials (e.g. lecture notes) that explain the concept of G-expectation in simple terms? I searched, however my search was not fruitful.

Comment: Please link to what you want clarified and state more explicitly which arxiv articles you want clarified and what in those articles most needs clarifying.

Comment: - Thank you Carl, to begin with, a simple explanation of what G-expectation is (in simple terms), and for arxive, I agree with you, the one's I am interested in the context of stopping problems, such as arXiv:1912.07843 or arXiv:1812.08626 (from the same authors), but I'd like to know what G-expectation is, much appreciated